# Not able to render HTML from custom filter in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am trying to prepare sentence using html tags, but it fails to render HTML, instead it display with escape characters.

```
<p>
    {{ activity | prepareSentence }}
</p>
```

Created custom filter to use in polymer template.

```
prepareSentence: function(activity) {
    var sentence = [];
    if (1) {
        sentence.push('<a href="/user/'
            + activity.from_user.entity_id + '/'
            + activity.from_user.name + '">You</a>');
        sentence.push(' are following ');
        sentence.push('<a href="/user/'
            + activity.to_entity.entity_id + '/'
            + activity.to_entity.name + '">'
            + activity.to_entity.name + '</a>');
    }
    return sentence.join(' ');
}
```

Current Output:

```
<a href="/user/22/name1">name1</a> are following <a href="/user/21/name2">name2</a>
```

Expected Output:

```
[You][1] are following [name2][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TemplateBinding subsystem contains an HTML filter to protect developers against XSS attacks. Therefore, inserting HTML (as opposed to plain text) into DOM has to be done manually.

For example:

```
<p id="sentence"></p>
...
activityChanged: function(old, activity) {
   // build html
   this.$.sentence.innerHTML = html;
}
```

You now have a vulnerability, so make sure you screen the source data.

Comment: Like Django / SOY , there should be something like "|safe" .